# Display emojis with skin color variation in a textfield via unicode

Tags: android, unicode, emoji

I am currently trying to display emojis in a textview via unicode.
I am aware that changing `\U0001f4ea -> 0x1f4ea` and then calling `textView.setText(new String(Character.toChars(0x1f4ea)));` displays the emoji in the textview. However most of the modern emojis containing faces have an additional unicode character at the back, e.g `\U0001f1fa\U0001f1ff` for the color variant.

I am unsure on how to convert the 2 unicode characters into a char.

Is there a way in which I could use the same method by converting the unicode into a string in order to display all color variations? Do I have to use another method? Unfortunally converting all unicodes manually is not an option.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am unsure on how to convert the 2 unicode characters into a char

You don't convert the two characters into a single character; you keep them as a string, and the layout engine displays them as a single emoji.

The String constructor takes a string in the UTF-16 encoding form, and UTF-16 will represent supplementary-plane characters (U+10000 or higher) using a *surrogate pair*, which is a sequence of two chars. To construct a String for an emoji with skin-tone modifier, you need to pass in the UTF-16 char sequence. For instance, for a string comprised of the Unicode character sequence < U+1F91A, U+1F3FC >, the constructor needs an array of 4 chars, which are the UTF-16 representation for that sequence, [0xD83E, 0xDD1A, 0xD83C, 0xDFFC].

A Character.toChars() call will generate a UTF-16 representation for a Unicode code point. If the code point is a supplementary-plane character, toChars() will generate the surrogate pair for that character. But your case requires two separate Unicode characters, which can't be handled in a single toChars() call. Two separate toChars() calls could be used for the two Unicode characters in the sequence, but you want a string that has the combined array of four chars.

I'm not proficient with Java or Android classes, so can't give you the most efficient way to do this. I'm sure you could use StringBuilder, constructing with the first character then appending the second. But there may be a more-direct way.

Comment: I tried that previously, unfortunatly the textview simply prints \U0001f4ea

Comment: I've added more info in my answer above. Hopefully that provides you enough to get unblocked.